# Java: проблема с аргументом (String[] args) в точке входа

Tags: java

Запускаю приложение Test из консоли с параметром q:

```
java Test q
```

в итоге при проверке `"q" == args[0]` получаю `false`! Что здесь может быть не так?

Количество полученных аргументов выводит правильно (1).

Вот код Test.java

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int len = args.length;
        
        System.out.println("Количество аргументов: " + len); // 1

        if ("q" == args[0]) {
            System.out.println("with q");
        } else {
            System.out.println("without q"); //попадаем сюда !!!
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно было попробовать для начала вывести в стандартный поток вывода `args[0]` и потом уже, увидев, что в `args[0]` содержится именно то, что вы ввели, задаться вопросом, почему сравнение с помощью `==` даёт неверный результат. Уже куча подобных вопросов была. Ответ бы вы легко нашли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `"q".equals(args[0])`. Оператор `==` используется для сравнения примитивных типов либо для определения равенства мест куда ссылки указывают.

Comment: точно! Ведь строки это же объекты... Как я мог это упустить...?! Спасибо. Сори за глупый вопрос...